# Deploying a multi-service app to a cloud provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, heroku, google-cloud-platform, cloud

There are several tutorials on how to deploy a containerized service to the cloud: AWS, Google Cloud Platform, Heroku, and many others all have nice tutorials on how to do this.

However, most real-world apps are made of two or more services (for example a database + a web server), rather than just one service.

Is it bad practice to deploy the various services of a multi-service app to different clusters (e.g. deploy the database to a GKE cluster, and the web server to another GKE cluster)? I'm asking this because I am finding it very difficult to deploy a simple web app to a single cluster, while I was expecting that once I set up my `Dockerfile`s and `docker-compose.yml` everything would work out-of-the-box (as advertised by the documentations of Docker Compose and Kubernetes) and I would be able to have a small cluster with 1 container for my database and 1 container for my web server.

So my questions are:

- Is it bad practice to deploy the various services of a multi-service app to different clusters?
- What is, in general, the de-facto standard way to deploy a web app with a database and a web server to the cloud? What are the easiest tools to achieve this?
- Practically, what is the simplest way I can deploy a React + Express + MongoDB app to any cloud provider with a free-tier account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deploying multiple services (AKA applications) that shares some logic between them on the same cluster/namespace is actually the best practice. I am not sure why you find it difficult, but you could take a container orchestrator platform, such as Kubernetes and deploy as many applications as you want - in the same project on the same cluster.

I would recommend getting into a cloud platfrom that serves a Container Orchestrator such as Google Container Engine of Google Cloud Platform (or any other cloud platform you want) and start exploring around. You can also read about [containers](https://cloud.google.com/containers) overall or [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/).

So, practically speaking, I would probably create MongoDB and the express app inside the same namespace (and every other service or application related to the project on another container within the same namespace).